# One common script.js file in two html page causing errors

Tags: javascript, html

I am basically a beginner in programming world. So currently facing a problem that I don't understand in which way I should search this solution. So I am here for help. Hope someone can help me. I really need this solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Game1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Game2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, quis!</p>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
(function() {
    const p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    const textChange1 = () => {
        p1.innerHTML = 'textChange 1';
    }
    p1.addEventListener('click', textChange1);
})();


(function() {
    const p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    const textChange2 = () => {
        p2.innerHTML = 'textChange 2';
    }
    p2.addEventListener('click', textChange2);
})();
```

So I want to run this script.js file in both Game1.html and Game2.html.

But it causing one error
![Text]https://i.ibb.co/BPVBv4N/html.jpg
in Game1.html

```
script.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at script.js:15:8
at script.js:16:3
```

in Game2.html

```
script.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at script.js:6:8
at script.js:7:3
```

I want to use one script file. When game1.html access it I want game1.html to access only the code including id='p1';  and when its game2.html ,I want it to access only the part of js that include id='p2';
how can I achieve this, that the html use only the part of js that is needed not the others.

just like we use one css in multiple html .

note- I want only to use one js file no other sub-js file.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the element exists before adding an event listener to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the element prior to executing, wrap your functions in something like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('p1') !== null){
 //p1 exists, continue
}

if (document.getElementById('p2') !== null){
 //p2 exists, continue
}
```

Comment: Really Appreciate your answers. It worked. But If  I use kind of a big project, do I have to run this kind of code again and again, or is there any better solution for bigger project?
Thanks again

Comment: Ideally, you'll want to make an array (a grouped set) of all your IDs; and loop through them in a single call instead of having a million functions checking if they exist; if they exist you can bind a function to them or return them in a list to be handled (ie: existing list); you never want to overdo when you can do with a single procedure :)

Comment: Thanks . If you don't mind can you give a small example with the above code. That will be  really helpful

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/ilanpatao/wb3nuqas/5/ shows you quick concept, we have an array of ids, we iterate until the length (end) of the array, we check what exists and what doesn't - the console prints which exists which does not;

Answer (score 0):

Since the element with id `p2` doesn't exist in your first HTML file, it returns undefined. That's why calling `p2.addEventListener` wont work, because `addEventListener` is not on undefined.

To fix this you could add a check for if the element existed and only continue if it does.

```
(function() {
    const p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    if(!p1) return; // Just replace it with p2 for the other part
    const textChange1 = () => {
        p1.innerHTML = 'textChange 1';
    }
    p1.addEventListener('click', textChange1);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the same script.js for the 2 pages you need to check if the element you are selecting exists on that page before adding addEventListener like the example below.

```
(function() {
    const p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    if(p1){
        const textChange1 = () => {
            p1.innerHTML = 'textChange 1';
        }
        p1.addEventListener('click', textChange1);
    }
})();


(function() {
    const p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    if(p2){
        const textChange2 = () => {
            p2.innerHTML = 'textChange 2';
        }
        p2.addEventListener('click', textChange2);
    }
})();
```